# Not able to upgrade to 14.04 version from Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I am completely new to this ubuntu world ,

I went to upgrade manager and see that I have 12.10 version and not 14.04 version don’t why

but when i click upgrade for 12.10 also I am not able to do it.

I have selected `For any new Version` under updates.

Comment: You don't have to select "any new version" but "LTS version" as both 12.04 and 14.04 are LTS releases.

Answer (score -2):

You should be upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04, open a terminal and write the following and then enter your password(repeat untill you have the latest version installed)

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: You cannot upgrade directly to 15.04 You have first to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, then to 14.10, then to 15.04 It is probably better to stay with an LTS (14.04) besause it is more stable and supported longer.

Comment: We all know you cant upgrade directly, he will repeat the process until he sees he is on the latest version. If not he can always do a clean install after backup.

Comment: "sudo do-release-upgrade" by running this command again on the latest 14.04 LTS will I will be on the latest version .. or it is waste of time ..